# Как программно получить <data android:scheme.. из Android Manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

Мне надо как то распарсить манифест и отправить на сервер android:scheme  `<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />`  , а так же знать имя активити у которой этот интент. Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать? 
Взять весь контент манифеста тоже подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте в манифесте эти данные через `meta-data`. Используйте такой код для получения metadata из манифеста

```
try {
    ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
    String myApiKey = bundle.getString("key");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + e.getMessage());         
}
```

Comment: хм, мне к сожалению не meta-data нужна, а дата из intent фильтра - URI  для Deep Linking

Comment: А, к сожалению я вас не правильно понял. Поправьте тогда пожалуйста вопрос свой